# Get the row and column labels for selected values in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'd like to get the row and column labels for values matching some condition in a dataframe.  Just to keep it interesting, I need it to work with a hierarchical (multi-)index.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((('a', 'b'), ('x', 'y'))))

    a       b    
    x   y   x   y
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
```

Now let's say I want the row and column labels of the elements where

```
df % 6 == 0

       a             b       
       x      y      x      y
0   True  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False
2  False  False  False  False
3   True  False  False  False
```

I would like to get

```
[(0, ('a', 'x')), (1, ('b', 'x')), (3, ('a', 'x'))]
```

Please note I would like a **general** solution, that does not rely on the index being monotonic, or the particular selection in my example.  This questions has been asked many times, but the answers do not generalize:

- [index and column for the max value in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14941261/171236): relies on sorting to find max
- [Pandas dataframe: return row AND column of maximum value(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26880989/171236): does not generalize
- [Retrieve indices of NaN values in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641231/retrieve-indices-of-nan-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe): does not return row label
- [Return list of indices/index where a min/max value occurs in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36333402/171236): does not generalize
- [Pandas: Get each value's index and columns values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108108/pandas-get-each-values-index-and-columns-values): does not generalize / uses iteration

Is this really so hard in Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to obtain the ordinal indices of the True values:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), 
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((('a', 'b'), ('x', 'y'))))

mask = (df % 6 == 0)
i, j = np.where(mask)
print(list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[j])))
```

yields

```
[(0, ('a', 'x')), (1, ('b', 'x')), (3, ('a', 'x'))]
```